# Android screen recording with Untiy & React Native

Tags: android, react-native, unity-game-engine

I'm asking while looking for an Android screen recording feature because I want to embed a game created by Unity into react native to proceed with a screen recording.

I tried to record using Esset on an Android device, but the recorded video was broken and could not be played, or there was no recorded video, so I replaced about three Essets, but I am struggling because it has not been solved.

1. Is there any android recording asset left in the asset store? Recorded images as well as video recordings must be saved.
2. Is there anything left in the GitHub address if it's not in the Asset Store?

I tried to record using Esset on an Android device, but the recorded video was broken and could not be played, or there was no recorded video, so I replaced about three Essets, but I am struggling because it has not been solved.